# Matlab: How to cut cells in cell array to the same length

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a cell array with different cells.

```
val{1}=[1 2 3 4]
val{2}=[5 6 7 8 9 10]
val{3}=[11 12 13]
val{4}=[14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
```

Now I want to cut every cell that I have left 2 elements:

```
val{1}=[1 2]
val{2}=[5 6]
val{3}=[11 12]
val{4}=[14 15]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
val = cellfun(@(x) [x(1), x(2)],val,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Santhan Salai  :)

Comment: @lambda, you are welcome. :) BTW, if your problem is solved, consider accepting the answer.